# How to refer static constants in gsp?

Tags: grails, gsp

I wanna refer a static string in a java class AppConstant in a GSP file. What should I do?
The AppConstant is like this

```
public class AppConstant {
    public static final String ROLE_ADMIN = "ROLE_ADMIN";
}
```

Assume that the java class is in the com.foo.app package. Thanks!

Comment: com.foo.app.package.AppConstant.ROLE_ADMIN ... that should do the trick. Or import the class and then just AppConstant.ROLE_ADMIN etc.

Comment: "com.foo.app.package.AppConstant.ROLE_ADMIN ... that should do the trick. " - In a GSP you ill need to wrap that in `${ ... }`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It isn't very common to do this sort of thing but to answer the question as asked, you can do something like this...

Define the constants in a Java or Groovy classs...

```
// src/groovy/com/demo/AppConstant.groovy
package com.demo

class AppConstant {
    static final SOME_CONSTANT = 'Neil Peart'
}
```

Then you can refer to them directly from a GSP...

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="layout" content="main"/>
        <title>Constant Demo</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        ${com.demo.AppConstant.SOME_CONSTANT}
    </body>
</html>
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you Jeff. Could you tell me why it is not very common to do this? I'm new to Grails. Is there any other better way to refer a constant value? I tried to define a property "com.foo.app.constant1='abc'" in config.groovy, but when i refer it in the gsp using "${com.foo.app.constant1}" it shows "com.foo.app.constant1" but not 'abc'. That's why I want to try the old way in Java.

Comment: It isn't very common because there aren't many good reasons to do this.  Whatever it is you are trying to do will dictate what the best approach is.  If all you are doing with the constant is rendering its value in the page, then you should probably define the value as a property in a message bundle and use the g:message tag to render its value.  If you are using the value to control some logic, that logic probably should not be in the GSP to begin with.  If you describe what you are doing with this constant value, I can help describe a better option.

Comment: Upvoted it just because it has 'Neil Peart' on it, besides helping me.